# "Narrative Describing Scholarly Research" vs. "Statement of Research Interests"

Tags: job-search

I'm applying to a tenure-track Assistant Professor position in the US, where the following are required:

- cover letter
- CV
- Narrative Describing Scholarly Research
- Statement of Research Interests
- Teaching statement

I'm used to providing a research statement, which contains my prior and current work as well as my future directions. Does the "narrative" part correspond to prior and current work, and "research interests" as future work? Or is my current research statement equivalent to the "narrative describing scholarly research" and the "statement of research interests" is just a rehash of my cover letter? No page guidelines were included in the job posting.